# How to check string contains particular word in TypeScript in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Can anybody suggest how to check string contains particular word in TypeScript in Angular? I have tried `indexOf` and `includes` methods, but throws error like `is not a function`.

Code tried is:

```
 if (this.filter.txtText.includes('second'))
            this.Showdiv = true;
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you have tried?

Comment: if (this.filter.includes('second'))
            this.Showdiv = true;

Comment: Well what _is_ `this.filter`? Given your rep you really should know to include a [mre] by default. Also this is **not** specific to Angular or TypeScript, what you're describing seems like a basic JavaScript task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `this.filter` is a `FormControl` or similar you need to access it's value first in order to make such comparison:

```js
const filterValueStr = this.filter.value.toString()
this.Showdiv = filterValueStr.includes('second')
```

You can check the actual JavaScript typing of `this.filter` by running:

```js
console.log(typeof this.filter)
```

And if you see anything other than `string` being printed out then you're likely to not be dealing with a string o what's on the `this.filter` variable

If you are 100% sure that `this.filter` is a `string` then you might be using a really old browser and you'd require a pollyfill